# jQuery UI + loads of buttons = slow?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm currently experiencing a problem with jQuery UI and many buttons. I have a list of 500 records and each record has three buttons. I'm trying to fine tune the resultset with some jQuery UI buttons.

Unfortunatly this completely clogs up my browsers. Internet Explorer (of course) is the slowest of them all.

See it for yourself on this link (test page though): http://jesperveldhuizen.com/ui/test.php

Are there any workarounds for this problem?

Comment: Use CSS instead of JavaScript to style your buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery UI is adding and removing CSS class names on mouse over and on mouseout of elements.  This can be a performance hit so the recommendation is to use standard CSS selectors to create hover and active events.

Like so:

```
.css3button { background-color: blue; }
.css3button:hover { background-color: green; }
.css3button:active { background-color: red; }
```

Though if you research enough you will find that jQuery implemented via class name adding/removing so that it could be 100% cross browser.  As long as this hover, active CSS selector method works for you (and it does for the major browsers), you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

So to make this an official answer:

The Javascript call `$('button').button()` is making it slow. If you are using that call only to style your buttons you can as well use CSS to do this. It will look the same and the performance will be much better. The only disadvantage is that you cannot use the methods mentioned [here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Button) but you can easily overcome that or might not even need them.

So in conclusion you'll be much better off with CSS.